# send mail error.log showing Socket Error on mailto php

Tags: php, email, xampp, sendmail.exe

> mailto doesnot work and error.log of send mail dispalys Socket Error #
>   10013Access denied.Please help me resolve this..?

my php.ini

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
; SMTP = localhost
; smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesC:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log = "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

my sendmail ini

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.live.com
smtp_port=465
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=*****@hotmail.com
auth_password=*****
force_sender=*****@hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem was my firewall which blocked sendmail.exe from sending..
>   made an exception in firewall and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is also an antivirus blocking it. In my case, McAfee's *access control lists* were the culprit. Disable access control in your antivirus, and you're probably good to go. It was quite frustrating though, finding what was causing the error.